# Inline dereferencing method return parameters

Tags: return-value, abap, dereference

I've seen several ABAP standard methods that return a reference to data as result.
`CL_ABAP_EXCEPTIONAL_VALUES=>GET_MAX_VALUE( )` is one of those methods. My natural inclination is to use this method in a single line, like this:

```
DATA lv_max_value TYPE i.
lv_max_value = CL_ABAP_EXCEPTIONAL_VALUES=>GET_MAX_VALUE( lv_max_value )->*.
```

Sadly, this doesn't work, because:

> Result type of the functional method "GET_MAX_VALUE" is not an object
>   reference or an interface reference.

The question at hand is: is it possible to dereference such results directly?

Whenever I am certain that results are compatible I would prefer to avoid the old method of dereferencing (storing the reference, assigning it to a field-symbol and then putting it into destination variable) :

```
DATA lv_max_value TYPE i.
DATA ref TYPE REF TO data.
FIELD-SYMBOLS <field> TYPE any.
ref = CL_ABAP_EXCEPTIONAL_VALUES=>GET_MAX_VALUE( lv_max_value ).
ASSIGN ref->* TO <field>.
lv_max_value = <field>.
```

It seems like a massive operation for a simple action.

Comment: Please be aware that I edited the question to make it propose a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that to add value to the question for future visitors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method `GET_MAX_VALUE` returns a variable typed `TYPE REF TO DATA` which is a "reference to a generic data type".

You cannot dereference generic references (*).

However, you can first [`CAST`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenconstructor_expression_cast.htm) them, to make ABAP aware of the concrete data type, then dereference the (now typed) result of the cast.

```
DATA lv_max_value TYPE i.
lv_max_value = CAST i( cl_abap_exceptional_values=>get_max_value( lv_max_value ) )->*.
```

---

(*) The documentation of [TYPES - REF TO](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abaptypes_references.htm) says that only references to complete data types can be dereferenced:

> A data reference variable typed in full with **`TYPE REF TO complete_type`** or `LIKE REF TO dobj` can be dereferenced in all matching operand positions using the dereferencing operator ->*. If the static data type is structured, the object component selector enables access to the components of the structure with dref->comp.

and this [documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abencomplete_data_type_glosry.htm) explains that a **complete** data type is a "Data type that is not generic."